# How to pass multiple string values to a Button click event handler in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

How to pass multiple string values to a Button click event handler in C#?

Comment: winforms or asp.net webforms ?

Comment: Uhh... why?  For the most part, you shouldn't be calling click events explicitly.

Comment: in WinForms using C#.NET

Comment: I agree with Austin, you should probably revisit your design.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you know the strings before hand you can use an anonymous function to capture and pass the strings

```
string s1 = ...;
string s2 = ...;
button.Click += (sender, e) => { MyHandler(sender, e, s1, s2); };

void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, string s1, string s2) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Without necessarily knowing the amount of string values to be passed through, maybe change the parameter to an array or list of string values. This should make it more scalable...

Comment: @sukumar can you provide us with sample code you'd like to modify?

Comment: @sukumar - Seems clear to me -- what part don't you understand?

Comment: That seemed pretty clear to me.  You also didn't answer the question of whether the strings were known at event attach time or if you were wanting to add args?

Comment: You could even extend the event handler to accept a variable amount of strings by: void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, params string[] args) {}

Comment: As in my code i dont want to use custom event handler like MyHandler.
Instead Is there a way to pass multiple string values to another event handler of button_click of .NET framework event handler.

For ex:
Assume i've an event handler '**Button1_Click**'
From this event handler i want to pass string(s1, s2, s3) values to '**Button2_Click**'.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Of all the other answers I was trying to understand, this one was the BEST one and the only one who solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on Jared's answer in the case that you dont know the number of strings:

```
string s1 = ...;
string s2 = ...;
button.Click += (sender, e) => { MyHandler(sender, e, s1, s2); };
button2.Click += (sender, e) => { MyHandler(sender, e, s1, s2, s3, s4); };

void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e, params string[] list) { 
    foreach(string s in list)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: As in my code i dont want to use custom event handler like MyHandler.
Instead Is there a way to pass multiple string values to another event handler of button_click of .NET framework event handler.

For ex:
Assume i've an event handler '**Button1_Click**'
From this event handler i want to pass string(s1, s2, s3) values to '**Button2_Click**'.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: @sukumar It is impossible to do that you are asking and still keep the signature of a .NET Button control Click event handler. You will need to create a method of your own that allows for multiple string parameters to be passed. The code that Jared posted and I extended are the simplest way to accomplish what you are asking.